# Boost Phoenix compilation error

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, boost-phoenix

I was trying using Boost Phoenix. My aim is to have stl algorithms that take a container instead of range of iterators, as described 
[here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/phoenix/doc/html/phoenix/modules/stl/algorithm.html).
However, I am getting a mess of errors on a rather simple code:

```
#include <boost/phoenix/stl/algorithm.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

namespace phx = boost::phoenix;

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    std::vector<int> my_arr{ 0, 1, 2, 3 };
    phx::for_each(my_arr, [](int i){std::cout << i << std::endl; });
}
```

I tried it on two platforms (Win7, Ubuntu) where I otherwise use multiple parts of Boost.

The error messages are rather long so I put them in files:

- [MVC++ November 2013, Boost 1.55](http://xstreck1.userpage.fu-berlin.de/err_win)
- [G++4.7.2, Boost 1.53](http://xstreck1.userpage.fu-berlin.de/err_ubuntu)

I can't really make much of the errors apart from templates not being compiled correctly, but I guess I am missing something rather simple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are using the wrong boost library. The phoenix algorithms are lazy functions which are explained [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/phoenix/doc/html/phoenix/starter_kit/lazy_functions.html). So `phoenix::for_each` does not do anything if it is called, but returns a function object which iterates over the range once it is called. If you simply want to use the STL (and other) algorithms on ranges you can use the [boost.range](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/range/doc/html/index.html) library:

```
#include <boost/range/algorithm/for_each.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

namespace rng = boost::range;

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    std::vector<int> my_arr{ 0, 1, 2, 3 };
    rng::for_each(my_arr, [](int i){std::cout << i << std::endl; });
}
```

Comment: You are right, even after compiling it did not yield the resulting effect, Range is probably what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to include the `phoenix` core before including anything else.

```
#include <boost/phoenix/core.hpp>
#include <boost/phoenix/stl/algorithm.hpp>
... rest of your program
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the compilation.